# Image Encrypting Getting Padding Error

Tags: c#, arrays, encryption, cryptography, rijndael

I am developing an image encrypting program. I have got two applications. One of them, converting image to byte array and encrypting with Rijndael. After it is saving encrypted byte array to a file. Second application is for decrypting. I am reading byte array from file. After i am decrypt and show image in picturebox.

But i am geting "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." error in decryption application.

Now i am saving encrypted byte array to a file this code **(I am not sure is it true way for byte array to file ?)**;

```
protected bool SaveData(string FileName, byte[] Data)
        {
            BinaryWriter Writer = null;

            try
            {
                // Create a new stream to write to the file
                Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(FileName,FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

                // Writer raw data                
                Writer.Write(Data);
                Writer.Flush();
                Writer.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

I am giving this method save file location and encrypted byte array. And It is worked. But i dont know, is it correct way ?

And my decryption application reading encrypted byte array from file method;

```
protected byte[] GetData(string FileName)
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(FileName);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open));
    byte[] a = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(f.Length));
    return a;
}
```

**And Error location decryption method;**

```
public static byte[] DecryptBytes(byte[] encryptedBytes, string passPhrase, string saltValue)
        {
            RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();

            RijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, "SHA1", 2);

            ICryptoTransform Decryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(password.GetBytes(32), password.GetBytes(16));

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes);
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            byte[] plainBytes = new byte[encryptedBytes.Length];


            int DecryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length); // I am getting error this line. Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.



            memoryStream.Flush();
            cryptoStream.Flush();
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();

            return plainBytes;
        }
```

**Encryption Code**

```
  public static byte[] EncryptBytes(byte[] inputBytes, string passPhrase, string saltValue)
        {
            RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
            RijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, "SHA1", 2);
            ICryptoTransform Encryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(password.GetBytes(32), password.GetBytes(16));
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] CipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return CipherBytes;
        }
```

**Full Code Decryption Application**

```
namespace ImageDecrypte
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string EncPass;
        private string line;
        private string OkunanVeri;
        private byte[] SifreliDosyaDizi;
        private byte[] CozulmusDosyaDizi;
        private const string SaltPass = "CodeWork";
        private string Sfre;
        private string dyol;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            file.Filter = "Şifrelenmiş Dosyalar (*.cw)|*.cw";
            file.FilterIndex = 2;
            file.RestoreDirectory = true;
            file.CheckFileExists = false;
            file.Title = "Şifrelenmiş Dosya Seçiniz..";
            file.InitialDirectory =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                dyol = file.FileName;
                string DosyaAdi = file.SafeFileName;
                label1.Text = DosyaAdi;
                Sfre = textBox1.Text;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sfre = textBox1.Text;
            SifreliDosyaDizi = GetData(dyol);
            CozulmusDosyaDizi = DecryptBytes(SifreliDosyaDizi, Sfre, SaltPass);
            pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(CozulmusDosyaDizi);
        }

        public static byte[] DecryptBytes(byte[] encryptedBytes, string passPhrase, string saltValue)
        {
            RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();

            RijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, "SHA1", 2);

            ICryptoTransform Decryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(password.GetBytes(32), password.GetBytes(16));

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes);
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            byte[] plainBytes = new byte[encryptedBytes.Length];


            int DecryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);


            memoryStream.Flush();
            cryptoStream.Flush();
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();

            return plainBytes.Take(DecryptedCount).ToArray();
        }

        public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }

        //File To Byte Array        ###################################################################
        protected byte[] GetData(string FileName)
        {
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(FileName);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open));
            byte[] a = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(f.Length));
            return a;
        }
        //File To Byte Array        ###################################################################
    }
}
```

**Full Code Encryption Application**

```
namespace ImageEncrypte
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string EncPass;
        private byte[] byteArrayForImage;
        private byte[] byteArrayCoded;
        private const string SaltPass = "CodeWork";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            file.Filter = "Jpeg Dosyası |*.jpg| Png Dosyası|*.png";
            file.FilterIndex = 2;
            file.RestoreDirectory = true;
            file.CheckFileExists = false;
            file.Title = "Bir İmaj Dosyası Seçiniz..";
            file.InitialDirectory =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            EncPass = textBox1.Text;
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string DosyaYolu = file.FileName;
                string DosyaAdi = file.SafeFileName;
                label1.Text = DosyaAdi;
                Image img = Image.FromFile(DosyaYolu);
                pictureBox1.Image = img;
                byteArrayForImage = imageToByteArray(img);
                byteArrayCoded = EncryptBytes(byteArrayForImage, EncPass, SaltPass);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sf = new SaveFileDialog();
            sf.Title = "Şifrelenmiş Dosyayı Kaydet";
            sf.CheckFileExists = false;
            sf.CheckPathExists = true;
            sf.RestoreDirectory = true;
            sf.DefaultExt = "cw";
            sf.FileName = "EncodedFile";
            sf.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = false;
            sf.Filter = "Şifrelenmiş Dosyalar (*.cw)|*.cw";
            sf.InitialDirectory =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            if (sf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string DosyaYolu = sf.FileName;

                bool cevap = SaveData(DosyaYolu, byteArrayCoded);
                if (cevap)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("OK");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("PROBLEM");
                }


            }
        }


        //Image To Byte Array      ####################################################################
        public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        //Image To Byte Array      ####################################################################

        //Byte Array To File        ###################################################################
        protected bool SaveData(string FileName, byte[] Data)
        {
            BinaryWriter Writer = null;

            try
            {
                // Create a new stream to write to the file
                Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(FileName,FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

                // Writer raw data                
                Writer.Write(Data);
                Writer.Flush();
                Writer.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        //Bytte Array To File       ###################################################################

        //EncryptBytes              ###################################################################
        public static byte[] EncryptBytes(byte[] inputBytes, string passPhrase, string saltValue)
        {
            RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
            RijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, "SHA1", 2);
            ICryptoTransform Encryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(password.GetBytes(32), password.GetBytes(16));
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] CipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return CipherBytes;
        }
        //EncryptBytes              ###################################################################
    }
}
```

What can i do before going to be a crazy man ? Thank you and waiting your precious answers.

Comment: A cryptostream would probably be easier and more straightforward

Comment: Yes but accualy this program based mail transfer. So encrypted files send another man with mail. And decryption application download mail atachment and decrypt it.

Comment: You didn't show us the `Encrypt()` function.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt sorry about that. I edit the question now you can find it. I believe encryption and decryption is working. probably my writing file is wrong but i am not sure off course. Please inspect and thank you.

Comment: I don't receive that exception, though I did spot that you were not using `DecryptedCount` variable to cut off the array after it. (http://pastebin.com/jAw6qcU8). Give it some filepaths and see what happens.

Comment: Create a short sample, a file of say 50 bytes. Add the plain text data from the file, password in hex (48-bytes) and encrypted data in hex. IOW enough information to duplicate the encryption.

Comment: Are read file and write file methods correct ?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt you think my problem is not use of DecryptedCount ?

Comment: Only secondarily. You got an exception which I didn't encounter, so you didn't even get to the point where you could use that variable because an exception was thrown. Your file loading and saving code is definetly weird in the sense that it can all be replaced by `File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] content)` and `byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(string path)`. But I didn't spot any apparent errors in these functions. Use the debugger to make sure what you load and save actually has the right array size and give us the code which calls Encrypt() and Decrypt().

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt thank you . I am on traffic now. One or two hours later  i will give you full code.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Hey man i edit the code and write there full code of two applications. Can you inspect again please ?

Comment: *Not reproducuable*. I reconstructed both applications, encrypted a file and decrypted it without problems. Try to decrypt this (http://www.file-upload.net/download-11427818/EncodedFile.cw.html) with the password "testpw" in your application, it just works fine. The encoding of the passwords is however problematic, in the sense that your special characters (`Ş ç`) etc are **not** covered within the ASCII code page, so `byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);` is dangerous, it should be `byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(saltValue);` (or UTF16 maybe). Try using ASCII only chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Maximilian Gerhardt** Solution is here;

```
    public static byte[] EncryptBytes(byte[] inputBytes, string passPhrase, string saltValue)
    {
        RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        RijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        RijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(saltValue);
        //byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, "SHA1", 2);
        ICryptoTransform Encryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(password.GetBytes(32), password.GetBytes(16));
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        cryptoStream.Flush();
        byte[] CipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return CipherBytes;
    }


    public static byte[] DecryptBytes(byte[] encryptedBytes, string passPhrase, string saltValue)
    {
        RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();

        RijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        RijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(saltValue);
        //byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, "SHA1", 2);

        ICryptoTransform Decryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(password.GetBytes(32), password.GetBytes(16));

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] plainBytes = new byte[encryptedBytes.Length];


        int DecryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);


        memoryStream.Flush();
        cryptoStream.Flush();
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();

        return plainBytes.Take(DecryptedCount).ToArray();
    }

    public static byte[] GetData(string FileName)
    {
        return File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
    }

    protected bool SaveData(string FileName, byte[] Data)
    {
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(FileName, Data);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```